# Comment exprimer « to shame its inadequacy » ?

Tags: sens, traduction, anglais, cinéma

Voici un extrait de film (*avertissement* : divulgâcheur) :

> [...] Three: in certain extreme situations, the law is inadequate. In
>   order **to shame its inadequacy**, it is necessary to act outside the
>   law. To pursue... natural justice. This is not vengeance. Revenge is
>   not a valid motive, it's an emotional response. No, not vengeance.
>   Punishment.
>
> [ *The Punisher*, (J. Hensleighsur) 2004,  [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0330793/quotes/qt0432220), je souligne ]

La notion de (faire) [*honte*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/shame/611029) a son rôle à jouer dans la sémantique du verbe *to shame* et on a aussi un sens comme « to [disgrace](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/disgrace/575924) by surpassing » ([AHDotEL](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=shame&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)) [ possiblement qqc. comme *couvrir de honte en déclassant* ] ; je ne prends pas position sur le terme ou ses acceptions en langue anglaise mais il me semble qu'il s'agit ici d'une « action » reliée au caractère inadéquat de la loi dans certains cas extrêmes (ici, le cas de l'ignominie du  crime organisé etc.), certainement pas un thème nouveau ni abordé avec nuance dans le film. Dans un sous-titre (dont on ne peut garantir l'authenticité), on a employé le verbe [*dénoncer*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9noncer) avec le nom [*insuffisance*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/inadequacy/588261) (« Pour dénoncer cette insuffisance, il faut agir en marge de la loi... » etc.) ce qui m'apparaît trop nuancé ou relevant de l'euphémisme vu le contexte (la situation, le personnage de bande dessinée, le [ton](https://youtu.be/CJrjvmq-4_0?t=106) solennel) et l'original en langue anglaise.

---

- Peut-on expliquer pourquoi on trouverait adéquat ou non le sens ou
  l'emploi de *dénoncer cette insuffisance* dans ce contexte ou autrement
  quels termes ou tour choisirait-on pour traduire l'original ou de
  quelle manière en langue française exprime-t-on l'action (le verbe et
  son complément, introduits par une préposition) ici ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Afin de **confondre** cette inadéquation...

En réfléchissant à la formulation de la phrase, j'ai pensé au verbe *confondre* et cette intuition me semble au moins en partie étayée au lexique, si on autorisait peut-être une extension au « caractère » de l'inanimé, pour ainsi dire. En effet, le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/confondre) associe ce verbe à l'animé ou par métonymie à un de ses caractères avec un sens comme « troubler de honte » entre autres ; d'accord, c'est normalement une personne (l'animé) qui est confondue etc., mais [Ac.9](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/confondre) a au sens 5 « Ruiner, réduire à l'impuissance » (par ex. *Confondre l'hérésie*) sens qu'on dit *classique* et au sens 4, par métonymie « Convaincre d'une faute, réduire au silence » (par ex. *confondre le mensonge*). [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/confondre) présente des sens comme « Mettre en désordre, déconcerter, humilier » et « Convaincre en causant de la honte, réduire à ne savoir que répondre ».

Je préfère le démonstratif (*cette*) au possessif (*son*), peut-être pour mieux isoler ce qu'on veut exactement « pourfendre ». Je trouve l'emploi du verbe *confondre* avec la locution prépositive *afin de* et le complément *inadéquation*, recherché et péremptoire, ce qui convient à mon avis au contexte de cette déclaration (finale) d'intention du personnage.

Comment: Je sélectionne ma propre réponse simplement parce que j'ai une très très forte intuition en ce qui a trait au verbe _confondre_ dans ce contexte et non parce qu'elle serait objectivement la meilleure (je ne le sais pas). Si vous lisez ceci, je vous invite à lire les autres réponses et à voter. Je salue l'effort de tous. Merci !

Answer (score 2):

Le francais n'offre pas selon moi autant de possibilités que l'anglais pour transformer des noms en verbes. Les formules adéquates retranscrivant toutes les nuances d'une expression en anglais ainsi formée sont parfois trop longues pour des sous-titres, rendant l'exercice difficile voire parfois impossible sans modification de nuance dans un sens ou l'autre.

En l'occurence "dénoncer cette insuffisance" semble en effet doublement atténuer la phrase en anglais vu le contexte. On va plus loin qu'une simple dénonciation et il s'agit de plus qu'une simple insuffisance. On pourrait écrire, par exemple:

> Afin de démontrer cette honteuse inadéquation, il faut...

ou

> Pour combattre ces manquements honteux, il faut...

Mais ce ne sont là que des propositions créatives. La traduction originale bien que plus nuancée n'est pas non plus incongrue et dans le contexte le lecteur ou spectateur aura vite fait de passer au-delà selon moi.

Comment: Oui, « …dans le contexte le lecteur ou **spectateur** aura vite fait de passer au-delà…», mais en même temps il retiendra de l'ensemble des notions véreuses à l'effet que la contestation légitime c'est une activité qui se mène à coups de révolver et à grand renfort de TNT.

Comment: Merci ! J'ai bien aimé l'emploi de l'adjectif pour créer un apport à l'inadéquation (honteuse). Et combattre est un choix plus fort à mon avis que dénoncer. Initialement j'ai lu _démonter_ au figuré plutôt que démontrer. Intéressant !

Comment: (j'adore « divulgâcheur », ça c'est de la créativité canadienne !). On ne peut faire honte à la loi, plutôt au législateur ; donc la tournure anglaise citée est sémantiquement déjà « fêlée », ce qui complique singulièrement ses tentatives de traduction. J'emploierais : pallier (au sens moderne) ses insuffisances.

Answer (score 2):

Je commencerai par observer que la proposition est d'abord de nature paradoxale. ( agir hors la loi au profit de la justice )

Ce paradoxe pourrait être très facilement résolu en réalisant qu'on a d'un coté un outil (la loi) et de l'autre une idée (la justice). Un outil au service d'une idée.
Mais non! On ne peut le résoudre ainsi car cette justice dont il est ici question n'est autre qu'un autre outil puisque : *"This is punishment"*.

On a donc ici l'exposé d'un paradoxe qui tient assez la route en tant que tel.

Saint-Jacques évoque la possibilité d'un euphémisme. Je crois vraiment qu'il faille la retenir tant, faut-il ici citer le maître (Audiard), l'euphémisme est très souvent **la** solution préférée pour illustrer les paradoxes... surtout... ceux qui font... *mal*! ;-)

---

La loi est un outil au service de la justice. Selon ce que j'en comprends, il servirait mal son objet. => Dans ce sens, le terme d'**inadéquation** me semble immédiat.
Mais... en revenant encore au mot final *"This is punishment"* on peut se demander que fait donc la loi, en tant qu'outil au service de la justice, si ce n'est : punir, condamner.

Et c'est suivant cette considération que l'**insuffisance** se justifie. Par comparaison , en concurrence avec l'outil *punishment*, la loi ne punit **pas assez**! Les condamnations qu'elle prononce, ne sont **pas assez** lourdes, les sanctions **pas assez** sévères. Par rapport au *punishment* pur, la loi est donc bien à proprement parler : insuffisante. Insuffisante dans ses sanctions, insuffisante dans son office.

---

Ensuite, l'insuffisance, on peut en faire quoi de ce truc ?
Oui! Effectivement! Comme suggéré par Laurent S. on peut certainement la *(dé)montrer*, la *combattre* etc.
On pourrait tout aussi bien chercher à la condamner, la tourner en ridicule, lui faire dessus ou que sais-je encore... Mais pourquoi ne pas tout simplement rester dans le champ lexical de la loi ? :

La loi, cela se *dit*. Une loi, cela s'**énonce**. Et, surtout, et de façon strictement conforme aux définitions des dictionnaires, une loi quand elle est inadéquate, cela se **dénonce**. Et si donc une loi s'avère insuffisante, on la dénoncera donc pour son insuffisance, on dénoncera son insuffisance.

Ces trois facteurs additionnés (euphémisme + cohérence sémantique amenée par *punishment* + appartenance au champ lexical de la loi) me font sans aucun doute trouver cette traduction parfaitement fondée.

<sub>NDaCOSwt : Je ne crois pas devoir ici m'appesantir sur la lourdeur qu'il y aurait à expliciter dans la traduction, la honte, le malheur ni quelqu'autre disgrace. On est ici de toute évidence dans le cadre d'un jugement de valeur et je sais que l'OP sait très bien entendre les charges implicites qui vont avec ce genre de truc.</sub>

Comment: Vous voyez un euphémisme dans le fait de décrire par « une dénonciation d'une insuffisance » la mise à feu et à sang dans la propriété d'autrui ?

Comment: Merci ! Votre propos permet de rationaliser la traduction présentée dans le sous-titre, et je ne m'y attendais pas. Je ne sais pas si le fait qu'on énonce une loi fait qu'elle s'énonce - une loi dispose - mais le lien avec dénoncer renvoie à la traduction. À l'origine j'avais inadéquation plutôt que caractère inadéquat en question. La nuance en contexte avec insuffisance est intéressante...

Comment: Ce «disgrace» fait sursauter le non-Hexagonaliste que je suis, même si, comme vous le disiez vous aussi plus tôt, on aime plutôt les gens d’ailleurs, et même leur parler qui nous semble si exotique :~)

Comment: Je trouve cette réponse très bien. Je ne désirais initialement qu’y ajouter un détail ou deux et la citer comme référence dans ma réponse, mais je partis sur une tangente et me retrouvai soudain avec une pleine réponse un peu en parallèle de celle-ci. Merci néanmoins!

Answer (score 1):

Je choisis de considérer le contexte le plus général, celui seulement communiqué par le texte et non comme le texte faisant partie du dialogue dans le film ou en tant que commentaire sur le film ; autrement, les mots étant utilisés avec un trop grand arbitraire  à  des situations irréelles, il n'est pas possible de prévenir que certaines notions ne soient faussées. De plus, je ne retiens du texte, *en lui-même plus que douteux*, que le début : avec « natural justice […]  Punishment » il n'est pas question d'autre chose que de se faire justice soit-même ; les mots « inadequacy » et « shame » prennent alors des « dimension » insondables, cela étant d'autant plus vrai lorsqu'on regarde les images qui leur correspond.

On peut trouver cette interprétation adéquate en cela qu'elle fournit un substitut logique à ce qui ne peut pas être traduit en raison de ce que je vois comme étant deux non sens combinés dans l'original : il est évident que l'on ne peut pas assimiler un acte de dénonciation à un acte à caractère psychologique, un acte qui vise à former les consciences ; to ce que le verbe « shame » peut conférer ce sont des sentiments de culpabilité et des sentiments d'infériorité  et les sentiments ne sont que le propre de l'homme en les considérant comme ayant une incidence négligeable chez l'animal; le concept d'inciter à la honte, puisque c'est ce que "to shame somebody" signifie littéralement, est ici appliqué à un concept, l'insuffisance, l'insuffisance étant le récipient de la honte, et cela n'est pas acceptable. On peut aussi voir dans cette locution un cas de création d'un nouveau concept sémantique puisqu'il n'est défini nulle part. Autrement il ne reste qu'un incertain désagréable;  est-on supposé faire automatiquement le rapprochement entre les insuffisances et les individus qui en sont responsables et en même temps comprendre que la honte dont il est question doit être la leur ? Est-ce autre chose que l'on doive penser ? « To shame » ou « to put to shame » est une action qui est amenée selon deux principes, l'un direct et l'autre indirect ; le principe direct consiste à faire des reproches verbalement, le principe indirect consiste seulement en une action dont la nature va susciter des reproches non prononcés mais que le récipient va déduire lui-même ; l'action peut viser à ce but de faire des reproches mais tout aussi bien cela peut être totalement être étranger à l'intention. Il est dit plus haut que l'on ne peut pas faire une assimilation mais on est forcé de faire un rapprochement de cause à effet entre un acte de dénonciation et sa conséquence psychologique inévitable qui est celle d'instaurer une certaine honte. Il est donc clair qu'il s'agit du processus direct et que l'acte n'est  pris en compte que par une de ses conséquences, qu'il n'est pas mentionné et qu'il n'y a pas d'autre solution que de le supposer. Il est, il me semble, fortement probable que l'action soit la dénonciation  et il est fortement recommandable pour en parler  de se rabattre sur l'action elle-même, ou la cause, plutôt que son effet.

ADDITION

Quel choix de traduction ou de transposition ferais-je en appliquant ce propos final « Il est, il me semble, fortement probable que l'action soit la dénonciation et il est fortement recommandable pour en parler de se rabattre sur l'action elle-même, ou la cause, plutôt que son effet. » Est-ce à dire que j'emploierais « dénoncer » ?

Réponse

« Dénoncer » est un choix typique en cela que l'idée de faire honte y est associée et que l'on peut souhaiter rester prêt du terme « to shame », mais évidemment il n'est pas impossible de transiger avec cette idée : le terme « réparer » (« réparer ces lacunes judiciaires », on doit modifier le complément) pourrait aussi convenir (la réparation suit souvent après la dénonciation) ; à peu de chose près la direction générale est préservé. Les responsables eux-mêmes peuvent être impliqués et la chose être abordée par le biais d'une  proclamation populaire/publique de leur culpabilité et alors une traduction comme « amener devant la justice les responsables de ces insuffisances » convient aussi.

Donc, oui, « dénoncer » serait un candidat satisfaisant mais seulement indépendamment  du contexte véritable auquel a été apposé « to shame its inadequacy » ; si le traducteur doit  prendre en compte ce contexte, qui ne correspond pas, en vue d'extraire de « to shame its inadequacy » quelque chose qui soit à la fois fidèle à cette locution et au faits qui devraient être vérifiés dans le film il ne peut pas pour plusieurs raisons ;  il doit  oublier pratiquement la locution anglaise et  déterminer carrémment quelque chose qui s'applique à la situation, vu que factuellement elle ne s'y applique pas du tout ; il fait donc dire n'importe quoi à cette locution. On sort complètement du domaine d'application des termes, le mal à réparer n'est pas une  carence ou une insuffisance, c'est une absence totale de justice ; le moyen de réparation n'est pas la contestation, ce qui n'est pas plus que ce que le mot "dénonciation" implique, c'est quoi qu'il en soit dit en explication du film (punishment) la vengeance par la force armée ; elle ne concerne pas la justice mais le tort fait à l'individu lésé. Comment réconcilier cette flagrante incompatibilité des faits et des termes choisis pour les décrire ? Cela n'est pas le travail d'un traducteur, ce n'est pas sa responsabilité d'interpréter au delà d'une certaine limite et cette limite est largement dépassée. L'image de cette réalité couverte ne peut pas être ce que les créateurs voulaient communiquer. Le traducteur ne peut pas faire ce choix, qui équivaut presque à contredire les créateurs. Si le traducteur ne prend pas en compte le contexte des faits par l'image il lui reste les apparences assez vagues d'un vocabulaire grandement sujet à interprétation mais il a la possibilité d'un juste milieu ; cependant il contribue à fournir une image mensongère de la réalité ; donc s'il choisit cette voie, il choisit de partager la responsabilité d'une représentation des faits grossièrement fausse, il appose son assentiment ; il peut très légitimemment ne pas vouloir engager sa responsabilité ; autrement, il est en droit de bénéficier d'une mention dans la présentation du film, une mention<sup>1</sup> telle que « les traducteurs ne sont pas responsables pour la corroboration des termes parlés aux faits qu'ils décrivent dans le film leur traduction ne dépassant pas le cadre du textuel. ».

<sup>1</sup><sub>Ce n'est pas une mention légale que je sache usitée ; je la conçois comme étant utile, en sa forme ou en une variante plus en accord avec la terminologie actuelle.</sub>

Comment: Merci ! Pouvez-vous svp. expliquer concrètement quel choix de traduction ou de transposition vous feriez en appliquant votre propos final « Il est, il me semble, fortement probable que l'action soit la dénonciation et il est fortement recommandable pour en parler de se rabattre sur l'action elle-même, ou la cause, plutôt que son effet. » Dites-vous que vous emploieriez _dénoncer_ ?

Comment: @Saint-Jacques Oui, ce serait un choix que j'approuverais, mais pas sans réserve ; ceci est une question de traductions d'œuvres faussées et je crois que c'est très embêtant pour un traducteur qui se respecte ; j'ajoute une reconsidération un peu plus explicite de certains points à ma réponse ;

Answer (score 1):

Mon expérience personnelle m’indique que les champs recouverts par *shame* d’une part et *honte* de l’autre ne sont pas identiques. La shame anglaise peut être une notion beaucoup plus faible que la honte française. Ainsi, l’anglais dira *What a shame!* là où le français se contentera de dire *Quel dommage !*. Bien sûr, la notion anglaise est large et sa traduction couvrira sans problème de nombreux termes français liés à la honte : *déshonneur, disgrâce, discrédit, humiliation, indignité,* etc.

L’original anglais présenté ici me semble indiquer que l’on désire mettre en évidence les limitations ou les faiblesses de la loi, les faire sortir du lot pour les exposer dans leur nudité à une entité quelconque, que je ne puis identifier convenablement en ce moment faute de contexte. Cette entité pourrait être le public en général (on peut se retrouver dans une illégalité perçue légitime dans certaines manifestations, grèves ou brisure de grève, par exemple, voire par certaines annonces radio-diffusées, circonstances qui sont souvent visibles dans la société, ne serait-ce que par les actions illégales plus graves qui traînent parfois dans leur sillage), ou alors les gens qui incarnent ou font appliquer la loi (ce qui est plus commun dans la fiction, notamment policière, mode d’expression pour lequel la vraisemblance n’est pas une contrainte aussi forte que dans la vraie vie).

On veut donc ***mettre en évidence*** ou ***exposer dans leur nudité*** les lacunes et faiblesses les plus importantes de la loi. Mais il y a bien sûr une idée plus précise qu’une simple mise en évidence. On peut mettre en évidence le génie d’Einstein et ce ne sera nullement honteux pour Albert. Pour noter la spécificité su cas, on peut facilement glisser vers le verbe [***dénoncer***](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9noncer), dont une acception au TLFi indique :

> Faire connaître publiquement une chose de manière à la faire condamner par l’opinion.

On dénonce donc, mais on fait peser le fardeau de la condamnation à l’opinion. Cette condamnation faite par tous mais provoquée par les actes et/ou les paroles d’un seul ou d’une poignée, nous amène doucement vers cette notion véhiculée par le verbe *to shame* de l’original anglais. Mais la notion n’est pas aussi directement exprimée. Elle requiert  quelques ricochets pour arriver à bon port. On pourrait peut-être faire mieux.

Je pensais initialement au verbe [***accuser***](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/accuser), dont Zola fit un emploi absolu passé à l’Histoire comme titre de son fameux article ***J’accuse***. Il est puissant, mais il s’intègre mal au contexte cité.

Il y a une idée de confrontation avec des textes de loi qui limitent la justice, et auxquels on entend [se coltailler](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=9W1QOERZr95E.html) et démontrer que l’esprit des lois et de la justice ne peut que triompher d’une loi mal faite.

Peut-être que l’idée de ***démontrer l’inanité*** d’une loi transmettrait plus directement à la fois l’idée de honte et celle de confrontation ? Mais cela fut-il le cas, il reste le couple *inadequate/inadequacy* qui se répondent entre les deux premières phrases. Un adjectif équivalent à *inanité* est beaucoup trop rare en français, si même il existe, pour pouvoir rendre cet aspect du texte anglais.

Il y a aussi qu’on ne cherche pas autant à démontrer qu’à réparer une situation, à se faire le bras d’une justice auquel la loi n’en fournit pas (ou plus) d’assez longs. Il y a ici une idée que la loi DOIT faire respecter la justice, mais qu’elle en est incapable en certaines circonstances extrêmes. La démonstration n’est pas le principal but recherché, la justice est ce but. Mais on veut aussi fouetter la loi, l’obliger à revoir ses méthodes afin qu’elle puisse dans le futur agir comme il se doit, et non en obligeant la justice à user de méthodes illégales.

Peut-être une traduction plus libre transmettrait-elle mieux le tout ?

> Trois : dans certaines circonstances, la loi se trouve impuissante. **Pour fouetter cette impuissance**, il devient nécessaire d’agir en marge la loi. De se mettre au service d’une... justice naturelle. [...]

---

<sub>Il demeure quelques problèmes pour la dernière partie de la description (ni *vengeance* ni *punishment* ne sont introduits par un article, mais il me semble difficile de les traîter l’un et l’autre identiquement en français, le premier s’introduirait naturellement par *la*, mais le second par *une*. Cité ci-dessous pour mémoire :</sub>

> <sub>Three: in certain extreme situations, the law is inadequate. In order to shame its inadequacy, it is necessary to act outside the law. To pursue... natural justice. **This is not vengeance**. Revenge is not a valid motive, it's an emotional response. **No, not vengeance. Punishment.**</sub>

Comment: Merci ! J'aime bien l'idée d'_exposer dans leur nudité_, qui se rapproche à certains égards d'une intuition très forte (mais non exprimée en question ni ailleurs) que j'ai pour cette traduction. J'ai essayé de formuler la question pour qu'on ait moins à s'intéresser au sens anglais ou aux questions plus sérieuses qu'on pourrait soulever relativement au thème de l'extrait. Quand je me suis posé la question, il m'a fallu plusieurs minutes pour identifier un élément de réponse satisfaisant. C'est seulement en vérifiant au lexique que j'ai pu voir que mon intuition était reliée par la sémantique..

Comment: au verbe original en anglais. Je crois que c'est la construction ou la tournure qui m'amène à trouver ici, plus que la sémantique. On aime la réflexion. Je me propose éventuellement de répondre. Merci !

Answer (score 1):

Il s'agit de faire honte à la loi en montrant qu'elle n'est pas correcte. On pourrait donc dire aussi "prouver son inutilité" ou "démontrer son inutilité" ou "montrer son inutilité". Ici le caractère péjoratif de "inutilité" renvoie au caractère accusateur de "shame". On peut aussi utiliser le mot "insuffisance".